# Using OpenSubKey not finding node that exists

Tags: c#, registry

I am using the cookie cutter code to get a registry key object in C#:

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyNewKeyName\\");
```

After I run this code `reg = null`. However, if I switch the value passed to `OpenSubKey` to be any value in the registry under SOFTWARE that has *additional* nodes below it `reg` will **now have a value**. I've tried multiple keys with this pattern and it works. If I put any any key name that does not have additional child nodes it does not work. Ultimately I'm trying to read a string value inside of `MyNewKeyName`.

Why does my code not work and `reg` get populated if my key does not have any additional nodes below it?

Comment: Does it help to use `"SOFTWARE\\MyNewKeyName"` instead of `"SOFTWARE\\MyNewKeyName\\"`?

Comment: Maybe, you haven't access to `HKLM` node.

Comment: How was the registry key MyNewKeyName created?

Comment: I created the key myself manually using the Registry Editor. The thing is I'm able to read other keys with additional children nodes. I also checked permissions and they were the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it turns out that the values in the '32-bit' registry and the '64-bit' registry are not identical. So when viewing the registry via 'regedit' and seeing *everything*, programatically you may not and that's the issue I was running into. I noticed this by running `GetSubKeyNames()` and inspecting the keys returned. The quick answer is to check both versions of the registry to find the value sought:

```
    //Check the 64-bit registry for "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE" 1st:
    RegistryKey localMachineRegistry64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
    RegistryKey reg64 = localMachineRegistry64.OpenSubKey(registryKeyLocation, false);

    if (reg64 != null)
    {
        return reg64.GetValue(registryKeyName, true).ToString();
    }

    //Check the 32-bit registry for "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE" if not found in the 64-bit registry:
    RegistryKey localMachineRegistry32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
    RegistryKey reg32 = localMachineRegistry32.OpenSubKey(registryKeyLocation, false);

    if (reg32 != null)
    {
        return reg32.GetValue(registryKeyName, true).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are compiling it as x86 instead of compiling it as an x64 application. Follow the below steps:

1. Right click on *Project*
2. Select *Properties*
3. Select the *Build* tab
4. Change "Platform Target" to "x64"
5. Now run the project.

Comment: Well, don't do that either, use AnyCPU.  Untick "Prefer 32-bit" in VS2012 and up.

Comment: Neither of those options worked. It was already set to 'Any CPU'. I tried just to humor targeting x64 only and that produced the same result.

Comment: I voted up because the solution was a derivative of a 32 bit and 64 bit issue.